# Как спрятать ряды таблицы?

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день профессионалы. Как спрятать таблицу, кликая по "шапке таблицы"? Сейчас я это делаю через Javascript, а в тэг ряда таблицы  вставляю

```
  echo '<table class="table_dep2">';
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $entries['count']; $i++){array_push($result,$entries[$i]["department"][0]);} $result=array_unique($result);  sort($result); 
    echo '<tr><th colspan="4">Отделы</th></tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < (count($result)/4)+1; $j++) {
    echo '<tr  id="hidethis">';
    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4-3].'">'.$result[$j*4-3].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4-2].'">'.$result[$j*4-2].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4-1].'">'.$result[$j*4-1].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4].'">'.$result[$j*4].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }           
    echo '</table>';
```

Код `javascript`:

```
<script>
function toggle() {
 if( document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display=='none' ){
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = '';
 }else{
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
</script>
```

И ссылка перехода:

```
<a href="#null" onclick="toggle()">Показать ОТДЕЛЫ:</a>
```

ВОПРОС: Как только у меня генерируются ряды таблиц кодом `php`, то скрыть их уже не получается. Не понимаю почему, ведь тэг `tr` же остается всегда, и он один на все `td`. Может есть вообще другой способ как это сделать? спс

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: у вас функция `getElementById` при скрытии возвращает только первую строку, а не все. Если надо скрыть несколько, работайте с классом, а не идентификатором. _(если проблема в этом, конечно,а то я мало что понял)_

Comment: ой это случайно попало..

Comment: Приложите пример верстки в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы вызываете функцию раньше, чем определяете её.

Либо поместите js выше разметки, либо используйте такой вариант (задайте id Вашей ссылке и клик повесьте непосредственно в js, а не в разметке):

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.onclick = function toggle() {
 if( document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display=='none' ){
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = '';
 }else{
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr id="hidethis">
<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4-3].'">'.$result[$j*4-3].'</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4-2].'">'.$result[$j*4-2].'</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4-1].'">'.$result[$j*4-1].'</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost/index2.php?dep_link='.$result[$j*4].'">'.$result[$j*4].'</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<a href="#null" id="link">Показать ОТДЕЛЫ:</a>
```